# error in calling Web Service

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am not able to call a`web service` even after adding `kSOAP 2 library jar` file.

Source code :

```
  package com.example.web;  

  import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;  
  import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;  
  import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
  import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;  
  import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;  

  import android.app.Activity;  
  import android.os.Bundle;  
  import android.widget.TextView;  
  import android.widget.Toast;  

  public class MyWebCall extends Activity {      
TextView tv;  
String Name_Space="http://web.exampl.com/";  
String Method_Name="add";  
String Soap_Action="http://web.exampl.com/add";  
String URL="http://MyServerIPaddress:8081/WebService/services/MyWebService?wsdl";  
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
      @Override  
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);  
    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(Name_Space,Method_Name);  
    PropertyInfo pi1=new PropertyInfo();  
    pi1.setName("op1");  
    pi1.setValue(6);  
    pi1.setType(int.class);  
    request.addProperty(pi1);  
    PropertyInfo pi2=new PropertyInfo();  
    pi2.setName("op1");  
    pi2.setValue(9);  
    pi2.setType(int.class);  
    request.addProperty(pi2);  
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);  
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  
    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport=new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  
    try{  
        androidHttpTransport.call(Soap_Action,envelope);  
        SoapObject response=(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();  
        int result=Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());  
        System.out.println("Result ::::::::::::::: "+result);  
        tv.setText(response.getProperty(0).toString());  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getProperty(0).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }catch(Exception e){  
        e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
   }  
  }
```

I feel few classes are missing in jar. From where can i dwnld proper jar file? Pls help me.

Thanks & Regards,
Sneha

Comment: do you get complie errors? or do you get runtime errors? why do you "feel" that something is missing???

Comment: I got run time error. I felt so when I clicked on particular class like AndroidHttpTransport with ctrl pressed it redirected me to a page saying "Class not found and attach source".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport=new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
```

I have changed this line to:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

And it worked fine.
 Also thanks for the full package rekaszeru.

Comment: HELP! my PropertyInfo class doesnt have any of these: `setName()` `setValue()` `setType()` methods!! I have included ksoap-j2s3-full-2.1.2.jar .... i checked the package tree and the class doesnt have any of those functions , what should i do??

Comment: AndroidHttpTransport is deprecated as of 4/1/11...and no, this is not a double April fools day comment...

Answer (score 1):

For KSoap2 to work on Android, the core library is not enough.

You need the [full package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/files/ksoap2/2.1.2/ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar/download).

Comment: HELP! my PropertyInfo class doesnt have any of these: `setName()` `setValue()` `setType()` methods!! I have included ksoap-j2s3-full-2.1.2.jar .... i checked the package tree and the class doesnt have any of those functions , what should i do??