# PropertyInfo.getName() ... and many other methods cannot be resolved

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Here is a screenshot of my Project:

[image: This is a screenshot of my project:]

The lines hidden behind the error window are:

```
pi.setValue(namePart);
pi.setType(Integer.class);
```

as you can see I have included the `ksoap-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar` and also all the imports are in place.
Still `pi.setName("");` (and all the ones below it) is giving resolution error! apparently no such method exists in class PropertyInfo... I have already googled this and no one else seems to have any such problem anywhere on the Net or on StackOVerflow! Please help I'm stuck at the very starting point of learning Ksoap and Web Services!

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl+Shift+O` to automatically fix imports?

Comment: its not giving me any import related errors! Just to be sure i just tried it.. says 0 imports added

Comment: then it means the method `setName` is not available in that class

Comment: look at this! http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ even the api site doesnt have the functions

Comment: yes, you just answered your own question :)

Comment: But then how is this working ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674851/error-in-calling-web-service

Comment: i'm not a ksoap expert, but are you using ksoap library designed specifically for android?

Comment: I imported the jar that rekaszeru in that question gave a link to... that question has code that is definitely java(Android) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are using **ksoap2-j2se** library which is wrong. You need to use [`ksoap2-android`](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library in order to get it work.

Comment: I guess that was my blonde moment, feel stupid .. but its weird that I didnt find any link to that page through stack overflow! All links led me to download the package you can see in my screen shit :S Thanks a lot :)

Comment: hi Waqaslam, can you provide me the exact path for ksoap jar file ? I am not getting it and I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Updated link is  here: Finally It's working.please download

ksoap2-android-assembly-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar

from this link: https://code.google.com/archive/p/ksoap2-android/downloads